# Easier way for probability problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

> **Question:** Bob takes a math test with $10$ questions. He has a $70\%$ chance of getting each question right. What is the probability that they get exactly $60\%$ on the test? Express your answer as a common fraction.

**My bashy way:** We know that the successful outcomes (numerator of probability) is $\binom{10}{6} \left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^6 \left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^4$ since we choose $6$ to be correct and the rest $4$ to be wrong. Following in vein, the denominator of our probability is just

$$\sum_{n=1}^{10} \binom{10}{n} \left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^n \left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^{10-n}.$$

Is there a slicker way to do this probability problem?

Comment: Your "numerator of probability" is the actual probability, not the number of successful outcomes.

Comment: is this contest math?

Comment: @player3236, also the Binomial Theorem states that the "denominator" is $\sum_{n=0}^{10} \binom{10}{n} (7/10)^n (3/10)^{10-n}=(\tfrac 7{10}+\tfrac 3{10})^{10}$, or ... $1$.

Comment: How is $\binom{10}{6} (7/10)^6 (3/10)^4$ successful outcomes? What is $7/10$ and $3/10$?

Comment: Thank you everyone, i get it now. @MathLover 7/10 is the probability of getting one problem right and 3/10 is the probability of getting the problem wrong.

Comment: You missed $n=0$ in the sum, but I anyway think that the probability for $k=6$ shall be written as a fraction. The sum (the "denominator") is just $1$ , so the "Laplace-approach" makes no sense here.

Comment: @MichaelLi Yes and hence what you got in numerator is already probability.

Answer (score 1):

*We know that the successful outcomes (numerator of probability)*

look here: [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function).

*The probability of getting exactly k successes in n independent Bernoulli trials is given by the probability mass function:* $$\Pr(X=k)={\binom {n}{k}}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Therefore your score is the exact **probability** of 6 successes in 10 independent trials. Following:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{10} \binom{10}{n} \left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^n \left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^{10-n}=\Pr(X=1)+\Pr(X=2)+...+\Pr(X=3)=\Pr(X\ge1)$$

the result of which the probability that Bob has a result greater than or equal to 10%. So that Bob will answer at least one question correctly. Look: [0.999994](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%201%20to%2010%20of%20binom%2810%2Cn%29*%287%2F10%29%5En*%283%2F10%29%5E%2810-n%29) which is the opposite of the fact that Bob will answer each question wrong: $$\Pr(\text{all wrong})=\Pr(X=0)=\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^{10}$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^{10} \binom{10}{n} \left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^n \left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^{10-n}=1-\Pr(\text{all wrong})$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^{10} \binom{10}{n} \left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^n \left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^{10-n}=1-\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^{10}$$ $$\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^{10}+\sum_{n=1}^{10} \binom{10}{n} \left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^n \left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^{10-n}=1$$ $$\sum_{n=0}^{10} \binom{10}{n} \left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^n \left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^{10-n}=1$$